# Using xetex, I'd like to set the monospace font size for my entire text

Tags: fonts, xetex

I set my monospace font using `\setmonofont`. I'd like to be able to change the size of this font for my entire document, rather than use \fontsize everywhere. How can I do that?

Comment: Check this answer, if you are using XeTeX (XeLaTeX): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20043/setting-default-font-size-in-newfontfamily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manual of `fontspec`: 7.2 Scale

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec

Comment: Can you please also here say a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: It is exactly the answer, isn't it? Further more, it isn't a normal link, but manual of `fontspec`. IMHO, everyone who want to use `fontspec` should have a look at it.

Comment: You are right on two counts: One should use the manual, and you gave the precise location in the manual. However, the [link to meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/155585) I gave before still applies: It's best to have the answers _here_. Who knows what the section number in the `fontspec` manual will be in a year from now; then it'll be more difficult to find. It's always best to give a short example. Here, just one line of code would be great!

Comment: @HendrikVogt I agree. The link in this answer is not working anymore at this point which made it more difficult for me to find an actual answer. Here's another link to the manual: ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf

Comment: It has already happened. :) There is no 8.2 anymore, updated to 7.2.

Answer (score 42):

Use the `Scale` attribute on `\setmonofont`, e.g.:

```
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Droid Sans Mono}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Droid Sans Mono}
```

The scale can be:

- a number: 1 is the original size, 2 is twice as big, 0.5 is twice as small...
- `MatchLowercase` or `MatchUppercase`: this scales the font to the height of either the lowercase or the uppercase letters in the current roman font.

Source: Section II 4.4 in the [manual of the fontspec package (PDF)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)

Comment: `MatchLowercase` is brilliant!