# Setting default font size in \newfontfamily

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize, scaling

When mixing fonts in XeTeX, some fonts have quite different aspects for the same size.

Say, I'm using Linux Libertine as my main font and I want to use Latino Elongated for chapter headings. Latino Elongated is quite smaller than Linux Libertine for the same font size (11pt).

Is there a way to specify the default font size when loading a font via `\newfontfamily`, such that all text written using that font is scaled up?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}{My Font}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}{My Font}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}{My Font}[Scale=0.8]
```

Choose what suits you best.

In old syntax:

```
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{My Font}
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{My Font}
\newfontfamily{\myfamily}[Scale=0.8]{My Font}
```

Comment: @egreg I take it the [syntax](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EEVAd.png) has [officially](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#10) changed since this (helpful!) answer was posted? Would I be correct in thinking that `\newfontfamily\myfamily{My Font}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` is now the preferred format?